# Google Maps API disable street view UI

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3. Is it possible to disable/hide all street view UI in google maps?

I tried

`disableDefaultUI: true`

in the map options but doesn't disable the UI in street view.

I'm using the following code to display street view on a click marker event:

```
service.getPanoramaByLocation(marker.getPosition(), 200, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        var panorama = map.getStreetView();
        panorama.setPosition(result.location.latLng);
        panorama.setVisible(true);
        disableDefaultUI: true;
    } else {
        alert("No street view is available within " + 200 + " meters");
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: `disableDefaultUI: true;` will produce a syntax error. What exactly do you want to disable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use map option `streetViewControl` and set it to `false` like:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5, 13.4),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false
};
```

Comment: That's the answer I added and deleted. I read the question again and I think he want to disable the UI in the streetview panorama, not the control on the map.

Comment: @MrUpsidown ;-) Just before I sent the answer I see notification about another one. When I wanted to see it it disappeared. I'm also not sure if this is what he want.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaOptions

```
var panoramaOptions = {
    disableDefaultUI: true
};

panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/fXu5d/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in angular 8 you can do it in the following way:

```
"@angular/google-maps": "^10.1.3", --> package.json

<google-map width="100%" height="100%" [center]="center" [zoom]="zoom" 
[options]="mapOptions">
```

The options to use are:

```
mapOptions = {
 fullscreenControl: false,
 disableDefaultUI: true
};
```